# apt-get 307 error

Tags: 12.10, server, apt, updates

G'day

The problem is (for any type of mirror or package) with apt-get update:

`Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.org.ua/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  307  Temporary Redirect`

But:

```
$ wget http://ubuntu.org.ua/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz

--2013-02-20 11:16:39--  http://ubuntu.org.ua/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz    
Resolving ubuntu.org.ua (ubuntu.org.ua)... 89.184.72.161
Connecting to ubuntu.org.ua (ubuntu.org.ua)|89.184.72.161|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6792450 (6.5M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: Packages.gz
100%[======================================>] 6,792,450    463K/s   in 15s
2013-02-20 11:16:54 (454 KB/s) - Packages.gz saved [6792450/6792450]
```

Why does apt-get can't get anything (packages list at first) from repository?

UPD: looks like apt can't get some (??) headers while asking for packages list, the process stops on 'Waiting for headers'.

Comment: try this sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Comment: The problem is with apt. It can't get anything from the web.

Comment: Can you give details of your /etc/apt/apt.conf? HAve you added any proxy there?

Comment: /etc/apt/apt.conf is blank, no proxy

Comment: **Firewall don't like "Debian" user agent as User-Agent in headers...**

`sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf`

    Acquire::http::User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)";

Answer (score 0):

Try another Mirror, Go to software sources(Select ubuntu software center>edit>software sources) and select another mirror that near with ur country. And try cmd terminal: sudo apt-get update. If it's not error anymore so the problem is with ur mirror (http://ubuntu.org.ua/)...

Comment: Already told - the problem is with any mirror. `Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  307  Temporary Redirect [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]`

Comment: Also, this is server edition of 12.10. Everything is done from a command line.