# Proxy Blocking apt-get, Allowing wget/curl

Tags: apt, proxy

I'm having an issue getting passed my corporate proxy server.  I had an exception put in place to allow my IP address to pass through, but haven't been able to get `apt-get` to work.

`wget` can get to the Ubuntu repos without any issues.

```
root@server:/tmp# http_proxy=http://<PROXY>:8080 wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.bz2
--2014-01-24 09:17:38--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.bz2
Resolving <PROXY> (<PROXY>)... x.x.x.25, x.x.x.24
Connecting to <PROXY> (<PROXY>)|x.x.x.25|:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5178 (5.1K) [application/x-bzip2]
Saving to: `Packages.bz2'

100%[========================================>] 5,178       --.-K/s   in 0.001s

2014-01-24 09:17:38 (7.78 MB/s) - `Packages.bz2' saved [5178/5178]

root@server:/tmp# ll -h
total 16K
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root 4.0K Jan 24 09:17 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4.0K Jan 16 14:14 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 5.1K Jan 24 09:05 Packages.bz2
root@server:/tmp#
```

I setup my apt-conf.d proxy configurations.

```
root@server:/tmp# cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/30proxy
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<PROXY>:8080";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<PROXY>:8080";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<PROXY>:8080";
root@server:/tmp#
```

`apt-get` still fails with a `403  Forbidden` error.

```
root@server:/tmp# apt-get update
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
<...snipped excess...>
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex
Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources
  403  Forbidden [IP: x.x.x.25 8080]
<...snipped excess...>
Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: x.x.x.25 8080]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: x.x.x.24 8080]
<...snipped excess...>
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: x.x.x.25 8080]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@server:/tmp#
```

---

<sup>PROXY replaces my proxy server's FQDN</sup>

Comment: the answer is already with you, try this : `root@server:/tmp# http_proxy=http://<PROXY>:8080 apt-get update`or `root@server:/tmp# http_proxy=http://<PROXY>:8080 | apt-get update`

Comment: @ggalaxy I did that, that's why I'm getting a `403 forbidden` back from `[IP: x.x.x.25 8080]`

Comment: my only remaining guess is : you'll probably need to ask the top Admin of the proxy server of your corporate to add your computer [IP_address] in his tables' rules of the proxy server, so you can update your Ubuntu. Its only my guess, because since the command is correct, I think the problem is not in your computer, its in your Admin's proxy server. He/She needs to add some proxy rules "of your computer" and allow you to access some updates, or other things.

Comment: @ggalaxy It shouldn't be the proxy, notice how the first command subset goes through; notice the `200 OK`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the reported *user-agent*.  This is why the proxy worked with wget and not apt-get.

I ran `tcpdump -Ai eth0 port 8080` to see what the http looked like and received a 'non approved user-agent' message from our corporate proxy.

```
<...snip...>
 <h1>ACCESS DENIED</h1>
 <p>The software you are accessing the internet with is not reporting an 
    approved "User-Agent"</p>
<...snip...>
```

The [Ubuntu Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/apt.conf.5.html) had a section that explains that configuration parameter.

> Acquire::http::User-Agent can be used to set a different User-Agent
>   for the http download method as some proxies allow access for clients
>   only if the client uses a known identifier.

[apt-get 307 error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258662/apt-get-307-error#comment322976_258662) provided the needed syntax, you simply add the below syntax to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/30proxy` (or whatever you choose).

```
Acquire::http::User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)";
```

Now, apt-get updates go through flawlessly.

```
root@server:/etc/apt/apt.conf.d# apt-get update
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
<...snip...>
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

Answer (score -1):

yes man, you were right from the beginning.(I think I understood your problem). From my understanding to your problem the way`wget` works with proxies, is not the same as `apt-get` does. How about you remove the 3 of lines  `Acquire::http::proxy "http://<PROXY>:8080";` from this directory `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/30proxy` or maybe remove the file `30proxy` and try update from the terminal uisng only one proxy address as in `root@server:/tmp# http_proxy=http://<PROXY>:8080 apt-get updateor root@server:/tmp# http_proxy=http://<PROXY>:8080 | apt-get update`. I believe it has something to do with **proxy** and **apt-get** configuration, which I have no idea to do it. I'm just trying to help you trying things.

You still have the option of **wget** the links of updates then fetch them then install them.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't work.  I've already replicated the commands above.  You can also see that there isn't any problem with the `30proxy` commands because the `403 Forbidden` is coming from the proxy server.