# Query regarding new installation of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, updates

Error when I am  updating:

```
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxyhost'
```

How to solve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proxy Blocking apt-get, Allowing wget/curl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409998/proxy-blocking-apt-get-allowing-wget-curl)

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the results of `grep -r proxyhost /etc/apt/ --include="*.conf"` and remove any `Acquire::XXX::proxy` where `XXX` is `http`/ `https` / `ftp`.
2. Check the `/etc/environment` file for proxy information.
3. Renew your DHCP information.

   ```
   sudo dhclient -r
   ```

Comment: Maybe `grep -r proxyhost /etc/apt/` would be better?